# SQL trigger problem - cannot insert into table (error 1172)

Tags: sql, postgresql, error-handling, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger in SQL that when inserting into the table, it will check the count of the people in the class and then compare it with the max number of people as listed in other table then depending on whether the class is full, it will not let the person to insert new enrolment

```
DELIMITER //
DROP trigger IF EXISTS training_session_is_full;
//
create trigger training_session_is_full 
    before insert on acq_training_enrolment
    for each row
begin
    declare msg varchar(225);
    declare max_of_staff int;
    declare Number_of_people int;
    declare course_id int;
    
    select max_number_of_attendees into max_of_staff
    from training_course_session
    where training_course_session.training_course_session_id = new.training_course_session_id;
    
    select count(staff_acq_person_id) into Number_of_people
    from training_enrolment
    where training_enrolment.training_course_session_id = new.training_course_session_id;
    
    select training_course_session_id into course_id
    from training_enrolment
    where training_enrolment.training_course_session_id = new.training_course_session_id;
    
    if new.training_course_session_id = course_id
    and Number_of_people + 1 > max_of_staff then
   set msg = 'ERROR' ;
    signal SQLSTATE '45000' set message_text = msg;
    end if;
    
end
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I need to the trigger to count the number of people and compare it to the max number of people then see whether is it full and if it is show to show -1
when i try inserting into the table, it show error of 1172 - that result consist of more than one row.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT)  variables are assigned with `:=` not with set. Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE) did you find that `signal` would raise an error?  Additionally: `declare` starts a block where (multiple) variables can be declared. There is no need to start a new block for each variable.

Comment: Sorry, but this code has little connection with SQL or PL/pgSQL. You should start by reading the documentation.